# Slim Framework v3 - Problems with PUT routes

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, slim

Since I have upgraded to `Slim v3` all my `GET` and `POST` routes are working well, but the `PUT` routes are not.
I have a class where I do something like this:

```
$this->slimObj->put('/path/{ID}', array($this, 'method'));
function method ( $request, $response, $args ) { 
    $response = $response->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    $response = $response->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    $ID = $args['ID'];
    // ...
    return $response; 
}
```

I use `Chrome 48` to debug my `Cordova` app and I get this error after that `PUT` call:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load 
http://example.com/file.php/path/149. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:4400' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.
```

I use similar callbacks for `GET` and `POST` requests and they work fine, I don't understand why it does not work for `PUT`.

When calling that from `curl` it works:

```
curl -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"data": 5 }' http://example.com/file.php/path/149
```

I call Slim API functions from `JS` using `ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'PUT',
    url: 'http://example.com/file.php/path/149',
    dataType: "json", 
    data:  {
       "data": 5
    },
    success: function(result) {
        // ...
    },
    error: function() {
        // Always getting error
    }
});
```

How can I make it work from `Chrome 48`?

I'm not so sure but I think that everything was working fine with previous `Chrome` versions.

Thanks

Comment: You could check with chrome inside the network tab, which headers are in the response.

Comment: @JannisM, none, there are no headers in the response because there is no response

Comment: Could you try to add theese 2 headers and check if it works: ``Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT``, ``Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just solved by adding this:

```
$this->slimObj->add(function ($request, $response, $next) {
    $response = $response->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    $response = $next ($request, $response);
    return $response;
});
```

before initializing any route.